# A function that compare a two lists of string

Tags: .net-core, f#, c#-to-f#

I am a new at F# and i try to do this task:

Make a function compare : string list -> string list -> int that takes two string lists and returns: -1, 0 or 1

Please help. I spend a lot of time, and i can not understand how to implement this task.

Comment: Do you have examples for the different cases? I don't exactly follow what you are trying to achieve here. Also: this isn't a programming exercise from school/uni by any chance, is ist? 

Comment: Yes, this is one of exercises in homework. I do not understand how can i compare lists... I understand how to compare two strings or two integers, but how can i compare two lists of strings ...

Comment: Maybe you can give a hint or small example how to start ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the task I assume what your professor wants to teach you with this exercise. I'll try to give you a starting point without

1. Confusing you
2. Presenting a 'done-deal' solution

I assume the goal of this task is to work with recursive functions and pattern matching to element-wise compare their elements. It could looks somewhat like this here

```ml
open System

let aList = [ "Apple"; "Banana"; "Coconut" ]
let bList = [ "Apple"; "Banana"; "Coconut" ]
let cList = [ "Apple"; "Zebra" ]

let rec doSomething f (a : string list) (b : string list) =
    match (a, b) with
    | ([], []) ->
        printfn "Both are empty"
    | (x::xs, []) ->
        printfn "A has elements (we can unpack the first element as x and the rest as xs) and B is empty"
    | ([], x::xs) ->
        printfn "A is empty and B has elements (we can unpack the first element as x and the rest as xs)"
    | (x::xs, y::ys) ->
        f x y
        printfn "Both A and B have elements. We can unpack them as the first elements x and y and their respective tails xs and ys"
        doSomething f xs ys

let isItTheSame (a : string) (b : string) =
    if String.Equals(a, b) then
        printfn "%s is equals to %s" a b
    else
        printfn "%s is not equals to %s" a b

doSomething isItTheSame aList bList
doSomething isItTheSame aList cList
```

The example has three different lists, two of them being equal and one of them being different. The `doSomething` function takes a function (`string -> string -> unit`) and two lists of strings.

Within the function you see a pattern match as well as a recursive call of `doSomething` in the last match block. The signatures aren't exactly what you need and you might want to think about how to change the parametrization for cases where you don't want to stop the recursion (the last match block - if the strings are equal you want to keep on comparing, right?).

Just take the code and try it out in FSI. I'm confident, that you'll find the solution

Answer (score 3):

In F# many collections are comparable if their element type is:

```
let s1 = [ "a"; "b" ]
let s2 = [ "foo"; "bar" ]

compare s1 s2 // -5

let f1 = [ (fun () -> 1); fun () -> 2 ]
let f2 = [ (fun () -> 3); fun () -> 42 ]

// compare f1 f2 (* error FS0001: The type '(unit -> int)' does not support the 'comparison' constraint. *)
```

so

```
let slcomp (s1 : string list) s2 = compare s1 s2 |> sign
```

---

<sup>Posting for reference as the original question is answered already.</sup>